# 20th Fox Century animation Strange color

Tags: animation, color

I'm working with 20th Century Fox animation and the colors in the rendered video looks very strange. This is the image as it looks in blender: [image] And this is the colors as they look in the rendered animation :) What's the problem? Thnaks[image]

---

This is the correct color before the rendering [image]

Comment: We need a bit more information in order to help. What are we looking at and how is your material set up?

Comment: I'm not a blender user, I need this animation for a video work with Premiere Pro CC 2017. I've downloaded the animation from https://ballyweg.net/20th-century-fox.html. I rendered the animation in AVI, HD 1080p, 600 frame, 29.97 fps. The only problem is this awful color after the rendering,

Comment: You aren't viewing in a "finalized" view, you might want to follow up by looking at the rendered view by choosing the rightmost sphere in the top corner of the workpane.